# How to determine if a network card is connected

Tags: networking, traceroute

External routers are a drag.  At times, they hang, and one has to physically switch them off and back on to reactivate connectivity.  The server cannot do much.  Yet, when it detects that a card is disconnected, it can raise alarms, or it can change routes, or, if not using an external router, it can even restore the connection itself.

I have two ISPs and a cron job that checks both connections every now and then.  Its core part is coded like so:

```sh
/usr/bin/traceroute -4 -n -m 8 -i $isp1_if -s $isp1_ip $isp1_tracehost \
    > $output 2>&1 || {
    logger -s -t "$0" -p daemon.crit "ISP1 unreachable on $isp1_if"

    # Code to restart pppd omitted
}

/usr/sbin/traceroute -4 -n -m 4 -i $isp2_if -s $isp2_ip $isp2_tracehost \
    > $output 2>&1 ||
        logger -s -t "$0" -p daemon.crit "ISP2 unreachable on $isp2_if"
```

The variables provide, for each ISP, the interface (`_if`), the address (`_ip`) and a not so far host to trace (`_tracehost`).  `$output` is a variable as the script can run silently via cron or verbosely when run by hand (as shown below).

For ISP1, there is no external router.  There is a PPP connection managed directly by the server.  On failure, the connection is restored, usually at the first attempt.

For ISP2, the one with an external router, I'd content myself with raising an alarm.  However, it doesn't work.  For example, when the external router hangs I get:

```sh
traceroute to 94.198.103.150 (94.198.103.150), 8 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  100.99.0.119  2.755 ms  2.781 ms  2.885 ms
 2  * * *
 3  62.149.185.219  4.780 ms  4.742 ms  4.738 ms
 4  62.149.185.206  4.697 ms  4.854 ms  4.916 ms
 5  185.1.114.77  5.045 ms  5.254 ms  5.534 ms
 6  94.198.103.150  4.653 ms  4.334 ms  4.404 ms
traceroute to 185.204.135.186 (185.204.135.186), 4 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
```

Although it reached no host, traceroute returned an exit code of 0, so the alarm was not raised.

After restarting the router, the output becomes:

```sh
traceroute to 94.198.103.150 (94.198.103.150), 8 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  100.99.0.119  2.862 ms  2.827 ms  2.815 ms
 2  * * *
 3  62.149.185.221  6.841 ms 62.149.185.219  11.377 ms 62.149.185.221  6.763 ms
 4  62.149.185.206  4.767 ms  4.888 ms  4.851 ms
 5  185.1.114.77  4.885 ms  4.986 ms  5.050 ms
 6  94.198.103.150  4.527 ms  4.467 ms  4.486 ms
traceroute to 185.204.135.186 (185.204.135.186), 4 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1  0.302 ms !N  0.341 ms !N *
```

I guess in the first case traceroute can fail because, as `isp1_if=ppp0`, it cannot find the interface when it hangs.  In the second case, `isp2_if=eth1`, it happily sends its packets to nowhere.

How can I fix my script so that it detects downtime in `eth1`?

Comment: Routers should not hang & require a power cycle. If that is happening, then replace the router.

Comment: What if the new router hangs in turn?

Comment: Are you saying it has? If it has, then is it the same model? Is it the same software release? If they are different & it has hung, then it may be a power or cabling issue. But again, have you replaced the router or are you just wiggling? Wiggling should not be tolerated...

Comment: The router is provided by ISP2.  I didn't change it, but I've had a different router by a different ISP and it hanged as well.  That's why I run the PPP interface internally on the server for ISP1.  ISP2 also provides a voice line (plain old telephone) and I didn't want to install extra cards on the server.  Note that the optical network terminals (ONT) sometimes require a power cycle too, albeit much more sporadically.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is at your end, not the ISPs.

Comment: Don't think so.  I feed constant power through UPS.  What else?  The root cause is that those devices have software running inside them, and software, AFAIK, has bugs.  (Consider also the amount of attacks trying to exploit such bugs.)

Comment: Have you checked your own logs? Are these lines leased? Do they go over PSTN lines, is this ADSL, is this FTTx? Your router, wha ever it is, also has software running inside it & has bugs. Have you checked ANYTHING on your side? Do you have your own public IP sibnet which you advertise through both ISPs via BGP?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151083/discussion-between-ale-and-bib).

Answer (score 0):

I excluded `ping` in order to not having to rely on a specific target host.  Reaching anything is good enough.

The simplest solution is to count the lines of output.  If it gets nothing back, `traceroute` tries for `max_ttl` times (the default is 30).  As the target host is chosen to be nearer, the number of lines output must be below.

The code for ISP2 changes like so:

```sh
max_ttl=5
outfile=$(mktemp)
/usr/sbin/traceroute -4 -n -m $max_ttl -i $isp2_if -s $isp2_ip $isp2_tracehost 2>&1 \
    | tee $outfile > $output  &&  (( $(wc -l < $outfile) < $max_ttl )) ||
        logger -s -t "$0" -p daemon.crit "ISP2 unreachable on $isp2_if"

rm $outfile
```

Note that the output also contains a header line.

I use `tee` to keep having `output` be either `/dev/null` when called by `cron`, or `/dev/fd/1` when called from the command line with an apposite option.